# Nestjs Provider with interface

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm aware Nestjs like Angular, don't allow using interfaces as providers. How can I work around that ?

I wanted to maintain the interface as the provider, to test it more simpler, or to eventually change the databases for example a `UserMongoDb`. The database objects are in a separate lib, I can't change them to `abstract` classes.

```
    interface UserDatabase {
        create();
        read();
    }

    class UserOracleDb implements UserDatabase {
        create()
        {
            throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
        }
        read()
        {
            throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
        }       
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class UserRepository {
        constructor(private repository: UserDatabase)
    }


    // ... module.ts
    {
        providers: [
            {
                provide: Database,// Wants a class not an interface
                useValue: new UserOracleDb('USER_TABLE')
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: read the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the docs, the answer is using the approach described here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#non-class-based-provider-tokens

In my case:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class UserRepository {
        constructor(@Inject('USER_REPO') private repository: UserDatabase)
    }

    {
        providers: [
            {
                provide: 'USER_REPO',
                useValue: new UserOracleDb('USER_TABLE')
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if we declare an abstract class "implementing" the external interface and we declare all the methods as abstract. We avoid having literals linked to an interface.

Example:

```
export abstract class IUserDatabase implements UserDatabase{
    abstract create();
    abstract read();
}
  
class UserOracleDb implements IUserDatabase {
    create()
    {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    read()
    {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }       
}
  
@Module({
    providers: [{
        provide: IUserDatabase,
        useClass: UserOracleDb,
    }]
})
  
  
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository {
    constructor(private repository: IUserDatabase)
}
```